# Can't add file in django 1.7

Tags: python, django

I cannot add a file in Django. When I click the "save" button, it does not save the database.

This is my `view.py`:

```
def add_product(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.userprofile = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('kerajinan.views.add_product', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'kerajinan/add_product.html', {'form': form})
```

`add_product.html:`

```
    {% block content %}
    <h1>New Product</h1>
    <from method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multiple/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </from>
{% endblock %}
```

`forms.py:`

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Product
        fields  = ('category','title', 'price','image', 'description')
```

and `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^add_product/$', views.add_product, name='add_product'),
```

Can you help me solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `enctype` to: `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Your current value (`multiple/form-data`), is not a valid method of encoding.

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads):

> Note that `request.FILES` will only contain data if...the `<form>` that posted the request has the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"`. Otherwise, `request.FILES` will be empty.

Comment: thanks but i have another error page not found at http://127.0.0.1:8000/kerajinan/add_product/kerajinan.views.add_product

Comment: file is saved. its done i change code return redirect('/kerajinan/add_product/', pk=post.pk)